# Custom Error handling in js

Tags: javascript

I have a form that takes students' information. On this form, there is an age entry with legal ages 8 to 20. If the age is less than 8 or greater than 20, a js alert pops up informing the student of the illegal age.

I am seeking for a way to create custom error handlers rather than just using the unfriendly js.alert() method. Any pointers to how this could be done will be appreciated.

Comment: You mean form field validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make error messages more user friendly here's one solution.

Create a div with no content. If an error is to be displayed, it will be displayed inside this div.

Here's how to do it with jQuery.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var value = $('input').val();
  $('#error-message').html((value < 8 || value > 20) ? 'Error' : '');
});
```

```css
#error-message {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='number' />
<button>Submit</button>
<div id='error-message'></div>
```

Here's a JavaScript solution

```js
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var age = document.querySelector('input').value;
    var error = document.getElementById('error-message');
    error.innerHTML = (age < 8 || age > 20) ? 'Error' : '';
});
```

```css
#error-message { 
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type='number' />
<button id='submit'>Submit</button>
<div id='error-message'></div>
```